# Find the URL of the current plugin directory

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, urls

So i'm working on a plugin where I assign a default avatar to anyone that comments. The line i'm stuck on contains a theme directory reference but I want to reference the image in the plugin directory instead. Thanks in advance!

```
$new_avatar_url = get_bloginfo( 'plugin_directory' ) . '/avatar-1.jpg';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [`plugin_dir_url()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugin_dir_url):

```
$new_avatar_url = plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . '/avatar-1.jpg';
```

Comment: Note that the file where you call this from must be in the root directory of the plugin for this to work.

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `plugin_dir_path()` ([link to doc](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/plugin_dir_path/#user-contributed-notes)):

```
$dir = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ); // returns "/var/www/wp/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/"
```

Or, if you only need the path inside your plugin, `plugin_basename()` is your friend ([link to doc](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/plugin_basename/#user-contributed-notes)):

```
$dir = plugin_basename( __FILE__ ); // returns "my-plugin/my-plugin.php"
```

Comment: Note that the file where you call this from must be in the root directory of the plugin for this to work.